# Is there API documentation for Kubelet API

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet

I know that the Kubelet process on each Kubernetes node exposes a simple API server, but I cannot find any documentation for it.

Does someone know of a resource that has it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It isn't documented anywhere (that I know of). I always end up [reading the code](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/4a6935b31fcc4d1498c977d90387e02b6b93288f/pkg/kubelet/server/server.go#L160-L174) to find out what endpoints exist.

Also note that unlike the API in the apiserver, there are no guarantees that the kubelet API will be stable between versions. Over time I expect that it will become properly versioned (and probably swaggerfied) and at that point we will provide documentation and a commitment to backward compatibility.

Comment: Yeah I had to do that also, the API exposes some low level metrics my product wants to capture, too bad it's hard to find right now.

Comment: I definitely agree that it's too difficult right now.

Answer (score 7):

Some kubelet useful API to curl:

```
http://localhost:10255/pods
http://localhost:10255/stats/summary
http://localhost:10255/metrics
```

Comment: mine is using port *10250*;
But the response is not readable.

Comment: @chinuy 10255 is a read-only port, while 10250 is default kubelet  port

Answer (score 5):

There is a new open-source project called [kubeletctl](https://github.com/cyberark/kubeletctl).
It documents all the kubelet APIs (document and undocument).
You can use like that:

```
kubeletctl -s <node_ip> pods  
kubeletctl -s <node_ip> metrics cadvisor
```

When you run `kubeletctl -h` you will see all the commands you can use, it also has sub-commands but you need to type the parent command and then add `-h`, e.g `kubeletctl metrics -h`.

Here are some of the [APIs](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/14344b57e56258e87cbe80c8cd80399855eca424/pkg/kubelet/server/auth_test.go#L110-L143) kubelet implements:

```
testPaths := map[string]string{
    "/attach/{podNamespace}/{podID}/{containerName}":       "proxy",
    "/attach/{podNamespace}/{podID}/{uid}/{containerName}": "proxy",
    "/configz": "proxy",
    "/containerLogs/{podNamespace}/{podID}/{containerName}": "proxy",
    "/cri/":                    "proxy",
    "/cri/foo":                 "proxy",
    "/debug/flags/v":           "proxy",
    "/debug/pprof/{subpath:*}": "proxy",
    "/exec/{podNamespace}/{podID}/{containerName}":       "proxy",
    "/exec/{podNamespace}/{podID}/{uid}/{containerName}": "proxy",
    "/healthz":                            "proxy",
    "/healthz/log":                        "proxy",
    "/healthz/ping":                       "proxy",
    "/healthz/syncloop":                   "proxy",
    "/logs/":                              "log",
    "/logs/{logpath:*}":                   "log",
    "/metrics":                            "metrics",
    "/metrics/cadvisor":                   "metrics",
    "/metrics/probes":                     "metrics",
    "/metrics/resource/v1alpha1":          "metrics",
    "/pods/":                              "proxy",
    "/portForward/{podNamespace}/{podID}": "proxy",
    "/portForward/{podNamespace}/{podID}/{uid}":         "proxy",
    "/run/{podNamespace}/{podID}/{containerName}":       "proxy",
    "/run/{podNamespace}/{podID}/{uid}/{containerName}": "proxy",
    "/runningpods/":    "proxy",
    "/spec/":           "spec",
    "/stats/":          "stats",
    "/stats/container": "stats",
    "/stats/summary":   "stats",
    "/stats/{namespace}/{podName}/{uid}/{containerName}": "stats",
    "/stats/{podName}/{containerName}":                   "stats",
}
```

Comment: This list is largely legacy. Many endpoints like /spec are now deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Not documenting it is a way of saying: don't depend on this yet, it's a wip. Some parts, like cadvisor which is currently running as part of the kubelet binary, are actually [more standardized](https://github.com/google/cadvisor/blob/master/docs/api.md). If there's some feature you'd really like to use but can't find docs on, I'd suggest asking on the kubernetes [sig-node slack channel](https://kubernetes.slack.com/messages/sig-node/), or the [sig-node mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/kubernetes-sig-node)

Answer (score -1):

You can run this quick command to list out all api endpoints. You will need to have jq installed

`kubectl get --raw "/" | jq`

Comment: Is this command listing the endpoitns for the kubelet or for the apiserver? For me it looks like the apiserver endpoints.

Comment: It seems to be the api endpoints for the apiserver for the above command.

Comment: This is for the API server, not the kubelet.